# Using attr of element as link of image

Tags: jquery, image, list, attr

The idea is to have an image in separate block of each subcategory menu list. When you hover the menu element of subcategory it adds the specific image. The link of image is in [data-image] attribute. So the question is: how to do this? **Each subcategory has to have its own image, that is added through js.** [The link of example.](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/YypJow?editors=101)

```
$('[data-image]').html(function() {
  var link = $(this).data('image');
   $('.titles').html('<img src="">').find('img[src]').attr('src', link) 

});
```

Comment: No elements at http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/YypJow?editors=101 appear to have `data-*` attributes ?

Comment: Hover Samsung - and first three elements. These [data-*] are to be added dynamicly, because of html structure - its unchangable.

Comment: _"So the question is: how to do this?"_ `js` at http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/YypJow?editors=101 appear to return expected results ?

Comment: No, because it doesnt use this:
`$(stuff_1).attr('data-image', 'link-to-some-image');
  `

Comment: _"No, because it doesnt use this: $(stuff_1).attr('data-image', 'link-to-some-image');"_ ? Is expected result hover effect that occurs at _"Hover Samsung - and first three elements"_ ?

Comment: I dont understand you...
**UPD** I get it... thank you... *) it helped. I needed to use hover...

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer:

```
$('[data-image]').hover(function() {
      var link = $(this).data('image');
       $('.titles').html('<img src="">').find('img[src]').attr('src', link) 
    });
```